# how to organise the card-deck body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have card-deck like this [image]

I want to organise these boxs : that the box Total width = ***Amazon Cost*** width + ***BOXI+*** width : 
[image]
below is my code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-column  justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="card-deck w-55">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 >Amazon Costs</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 id="amc" class="card-title"></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 >BOXI+</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 id="boxiP" class="card-title"></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 >Total</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 id="tt" class="card-title"></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a full width DIV (`<div class="w-100"></div>`) before the last card...

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-column  justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>Amazon Costs</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 id="amc" class="card-title"></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>BOXI+</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 id="boxiP" class="card-title"></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100"></div>
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>Total</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 id="tt" class="card-title"></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/PaLq3R5eXR